# Merged Socket->recv with perl on Linux

Tags: linux, perl, sockets

Sorry for the bad English, it is not my mother tongue.

I am new to perl programming and I'm facing a tedious problem for some hours now.

I have coded a simple Client-Server using IO::Socket::INET. It works flawlessly on Windows, but is broken on Linux.

On Linux, the first recv get both of server's communication and therefor, the second one is waiting endlessly for a communication.

Running the command "perl -version" gives me this result on Windows:

> This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2) built for
>   MSWin32-x64-multi-t hread (with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for
>   more detail)

And on Linux :

> This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2) built for
>   x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi (with 42 registered patches, see perl -V
>   for more detail)

Here is and exemple of a server:

```
use IO::Socket;

my $socket= IO::Socket::INET->new( Proto => "tcp",
                                   LocalPort => 2559,
                                   Listen => SOMAXCONN,
                                   Reuse => 1);

while(1)
{
    print "Waiting for a client\n";
    my $client = $socket->accept();
    $client->send("Hello, please connect yourself");
    $client->send("Username:");
    $client->recv(my $username, 1024);
    $client->send("Password:");
    $client->recv(my $cipheredpassword, 1024);
    $client->send("Thank you, Goodbye.");
    $client->close();
    print "Connection closed\n";
}
```

And here is an exemple of a client :

```
use IO::Socket;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

my $username = "";
my $password = "";

my $server = IO::Socket::INET->new( Proto => "tcp",
                                    PeerAddr => "localhost",
                                    PeerPort => 2559);

# Pick up both $firstServerMessage and 
# $serverAskUsernameMessage on Linux
$server->recv(my $firstServerMessage, 1024); 
print "$firstServerMessage\n";

# Hangs on Linux
$server->recv(my $serverAskUsernameMessage, 1024);

while($username eq "")
{
    print "$serverAskUsernameMessage\n";
    chomp($username = <STDIN>); 
}

$server->send($username);
$server->recv(my $serverAskPasswordMessage, 1024);

while($password eq "")
{
    print "$serverAskPasswordMessage\n";
    chomp($password = <STDIN>);
}

my $hashedPassword = md5_hex($password);
$server->send($hashedPassword);

$server->recv(my $lastServerMessage, 1024);
print $lastServerMessage;
```

I know that the easy solution to this problem would be to avoid having multiple ->recv in a row, but I'm also curious to know why it is not working on Linux.

I have tried to use ->flush and ->autoflush(1), without success.

Your help and knowledge would be appreciated,
L.C.

Comment: Why don't you want to just use low-level Socket? When the same code works differently on different OS, more difficult to understand why it is if you have a bunch of extra wrappers. Perhaps in this case (on linux) it will be more efficient and easier to go to the low level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with the choice of operating system, or indeed the language. The problem relates to the fact of how you are using TCP.

A TCP stream is just that - a stream of bytes. It does not matter to TCP how you write those bytes - you could `send` in fifty 1-byte chunks, or one 50-byte, or anything inbetween. The TCP stream simply represents the bytes, without message boundaries. It's much the same as file IO - a file on disk doesn't remember the distinction between `write` calls, only the sum total of bytes that were transferred.

So in your server when you do

```
$client->send("Hello, please connect yourself");
$client->send("Username:");
```

It could all get merged in one segment over the wire, and will arrive in one go at the other end. This is why any TCP-based protocol provides some form of framing - be it linefeeds, or message headers that declare the size of the body, or whatever. Some way that the receiver can pull the stream apart again.

For example, you might decide to use `"\n"` as a message boundary. You can then send using

```
$client->send("Hello, please connect yourself\n");
$client->send("Username:\n");
```

and the receiver can use the regular `readline` to read these lines back out again.

Comment: With readline and \n it works well. But why does the code in the question workes well on windows?

Comment: Also TCP/IP stack may be differently implemented in different OSs. Respectively the default optimizations of sending packets may vary too. IMHO)

Comment: For the reasons LeoNerd gave, use `print`  and `read`/`sysread`/`readline` for TCP. Save `send` and `recv` for UDP.

Comment: Thank you. With this information in my hands, I decided to create two small subroutines. 

First, `sendTransmission` adds a small personalised string at the end of the transmission.
Secondly, `readTransmission` overwrite the separator used my `readline` with my own. e.g. `local $/ = "!EOT!";`

It allows me to still send multiple line containing `\n` and allows me to send multiple messages one after the other without having them merged on the other side.

I still does not know why it was working on Windows, probably MSMagic.